# флажок Open server горит желтым при запуске

Tags: php, mysql, apache, openserver, ос

При запуске просто горит желтым и ничего не происходит. Не могу нажать лкм или пкм по нему.

Пробовал изменить HTTPS, жанглировал версиями apache и php. Ничего не помогает. Люди добрые, помогите

Comment: Порт не занят, проверяли?

Comment: Нет, не занят (Порт 442)

Comment: версии php и apache тоже проверяли на совместимость в разделе Настройки модули?

Comment: Попробуйте запустить от имени Администратора, возможно с правами доступа какие-то сложности

Comment: Пробовал от имени администратора и менял версии php и apache. Не помогает

Comment: если у меня какая-либо проблема с чужим ПО - я, для начала, смотрю логи, и пытаюсь понять чем проблема вызвана. Потом уже пытаюсь искать проблему в интернете.

Answer (score 0):

возможно запущен отдельно Mysql сервер или FTP сервер